# How do I filter through an Array with multiple objects in an Array and return lengths

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an Array with multiple objects

```
var List = [
  {
  name: 'John',
  city: 'Denver',
  email: 'johnson@mail.com'
  },
  {
  name: '',
  city: 'Dever',
  email: 'tom@mail.com'
  },
  {
  name: 'Mark',
  city: '',
  email: '',
  }
];
```

I have previously use filters to return a total number of names filled out.

```
// returned filled out names
let total_name = List.filter((c: { name: any }) => !!c.name).length;
console.log(total_name); // returns 2
```

What I am trying to accomplish is filter though all three or more objects and get total length of the items i.e 9 and get the total length of filled out items which would be 5 total length.

changes I made to the answer I accepted.

```
isFilledLength(arr: any[], status: string) {
  let y = 0;
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    for (const x in item) {
      if (!!item[x] && status=='filled')
        y++;
      if(status=='full')
        y++;
    }
  });
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var List = [{
    name: 'John',
    city: 'Denver',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com'
  },
  {
    name: '',
    city: 'Dever',
    email: 'tom@mail.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    city: '',
    email: '',
  }
];

function isFilledLength(arr, status) {
  let y = 0;
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    for (x in item) {
      if (!!item[x] && status=='filled')
        y++;
      if(status=='full')
        y++;

    }
  });
  return y;
}

console.log('filled', isFilledLength(List, 'filled'));
console.log('total filled', isFilledLength(List, 'full'));
```

Comment: I did some minor changes to your code for some errors I was getting on my end, but this works great

Comment: Added in the question under, changes I made to the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```js
type Tuple = [number, number]

function totalAndNonEmptyProps(arr: Record<string, unknown>[]) {
  const tuples: Tuple[] = arr.map((rec) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(rec)
    const nonEmptyKeys = keys.filter((key) => rec[key] != '')
    return [keys.length, nonEmptyKeys.length]
  })

  return tuples.reduce(([a1, a2], [c1, c2]) => [a1 + c1, a2 + c2])
}

console.log(totalPropsAndNonEmptyProps(arr)) // [9, 6]
```